# Making Api.ai parameters required based on source.

Tags: dialogflow-es

I am new to dialogflow. I have the following requirement.

- If user pings from api.i webview , a parameter should be made required.
- If user pings from facebook messenger, a parameter should not be made required.

Comment: make separate Intents then.

Answer (score 2):

To achieve this, you can mark the value as required in your intent, then tell Dialogflow to [use your webhook for slot-filling](https://dialogflow.com/docs/fulfillment#slot_filling).

When the intent is matched, your webhook will receive a request that, if from the Facebook integration, will contain the `originalRequest` from Facebook.

If you detect the Facebook integration, you can respond to Dialogflow from your webhook including a value for the parameter, and Dialogflow will not prompt for it. If you do not detect Facebook, respond without the value and Dialogflow will prompt the user for it.